# SwiftUi Fullscreen cover without using state variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

i'm trying to do a simple login screen using swiftUI.
i put my isLogin into a class and set it as an EnviromentObject Variable.

How do I use it in a fullscreen cover?
My class

```
class AuthUser:ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLogin:Bool = false
    @Published var isCorrect:Bool = false
}
```

My View :

```
struct UIController: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth : AuthUser
    @State var showLogin:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        homeLogin()
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showLogin, content: AfterLogin.init)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need a state variable or observed object in one way shape form or fashion to make this work. Can you clarify what you're attempting to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use binding directly to property of environment object, like

```
struct UIController: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth : AuthUser
    var body: some View {
        homeLogin()
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $userAuth.isLogin, content: AfterLogin.init)
    }
}
```

Comment: but it cant load anything, i got the Cannot preview in this file error

Comment: You should inject correct environment object for Preview, but this is different question. Anyway next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61335934/12299030.

Answer (score 1):

The structure you're attempting to follow is called MVVM or Model-View-View-Model, which is nearly a requirement for swiftUI I believe the only thing that you're missing is the actual usage of that ViewModel, or in your case the `AuthUser`. So let's dig into that.

#### View Model

```
class AuthUser: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLogin = false
    //Any other code, methods, constructors you want.
}
```

#### View

```
struct UIController: View {
     @ObservedObject var userAuth = AuthUser()

     var body: some View {
         homeLogin()
              .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $userAuth.isLogin, content: AfterLogin.init)
     }
}
```

What did I change? I changed your `@EnvironmentObject` to a `ObservedObject` because in your case you're not likely to actually be using an environment object. What are those special tags?

- ObservableObject, this means that it can be observed for state changes.
- ObservedObject, an object that is watching for state changes.
- Published, an object that has public availability.
- EnvironmentObject, an object that is created for the environment and accessible wherever in the app. This particular object is not immediately disposed which is why we removed it in your example.

So what's the purpose of doing things this way? Well it has to do with abstraction and readability. MVVM frameworks provide a way to `Bind` a view to an object. That binding means that any changes on the view change the data, and any changes to the data change the view. Swift makes this concept simple enough. In your case we're binding the `isPresented` to the `ObservedObject` and checking that objects `isLogin` state. If it changes, the view is also changed.